# R function doesn't recognize variable

Tags: r

I am not very familiar with loops in R, and am having a hard time stating a variable such that it is recognized by a function, DESeqDataSetFromMatrix.

**pls** is a table of integers. **metaData** is a data frame containing sample IDs and conditions corresponding to pls. I verified that the below steps run error-free with the individual elements of **cond** run successfully .

I reviewed relevant posts on referencing variables in R:
[How to reference variable names in a for loop in R?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47311904/how-to-reference-variable-names-in-a-for-loop-in-r)
[How to reference a variable in a for loop?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49311700/how-to-reference-a-variable-in-a-for-loop)

Based on these posts, I modified i in line 3 with single brackets, double brackets and "as.name". No luck. DESeqDataSetFromMatrix is reading the literal text after ~ and spits out an error.

```
cond=c("wt","dhx","mpp","taz")
for(i in cond){
dds <- DESeqDataSetFromMatrix(countData=pls,colData=metaData,design=~i, tidy = TRUE)
"sizeFactors"(dds) <- 1
paste0("PLS",i)<-DESeq(dds)
pdf <- paste(i,"-PLS_MA.pdf",sep="")
tsv <- paste(i,"-PLS.tsv",sep="")
pdf(file=pdf,paper = "a4r", width = 0, height = 0)
plotMA(paste0("PLS",i),ylim=c(-10,10))
dev.off()
write.table(results(paste0("PLS",i)),file = tsv,quote=FALSE, sep='\t', col.names = NA)
}
```

With brackets, an unexpected symbol error populates.
With i alone, DESEqDataSetFromMatrix tries to read "i" from my metaData column.

Is R just not capable of reading variables in some situations? Generally speaking, is it better to write loops outside of R in a more straightforward language, then push as standalone commands? Thanks for the help—I hope there is an easy fix.

Comment: as.formula(paste0("~", i))

Comment: `reformulate(i)` should also work

Comment: Thanks, all, for providing useful answers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For anyone else who may be having trouble looping with DESeq2 functions, comments above addressed my issue.

Correct input:

```
dds <- DESeqDataSetFromMatrix(countData=pls,colData=metaData,design=as.formula(paste0("~", i)), tidy = TRUE)
```

as.formula worked well with all DESeq functions that I tested.

reformulate(i) also worked well in most situations.

Thanks, everyone for the help!